# Shiny - Text style for rows of renderTable / renderDataTable

Tags: r, shiny

How can I show the text of the first two rows in a renderTable in bold? Can I do this without DT/renderDataTable?

Answer (score 3):

How about this:

```
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    tags$head(
      tags$style(
        HTML("tr:first-child, tr:first-child + tr { font-weight: bold }")
      )
    ),
    fluidRow(
      column(12, tableOutput('table')
      )
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$table <- renderTable(head(iris))
  }
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
    tags$head(
        tags$style(
            "tr:nth-child(1) {font-weight: bold;}
             tr:nth-child(2) {font-weight: bold;}
            "
        )
    ),
    tableOutput("tbl")
)

server <- function(input, output){

    output$tbl <- renderTable({iris})
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```