# Data Table Format Row by Row Number

Tags: r, shiny, datatables, formatting, dt

I feel this is a basic question, but no matter how much I searched, I can't seem to find a straightforward answer:

I am trying to format all numeric columns of row 3 of my data table as percent, and in addition make the cells grey. 
Formatting columns is quite easy and and I've found a few different options that format rows based on a conditions from a column, but not a straight forward way to just select a row I wish to format.

My code is a bit messy, and does a lot of stuff, so I'll just use the iris dataset as an example.

How would I format just row 3 of the data table (set numbers in all columns to % and make the background grey)?

```
server.R:

library(shiny)
library(DT)
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  df<-datatable(iris, options = list(pageLength = 5))
  output$iris <- renderDataTable(df)
})


ui.R:

library(shiny)
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Iris Data"),
  dataTableOutput("iris") 
)
)
```

Comment: you can check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41819339/shiny-text-style-for-rows-of-rendertable-renderdatatable and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34728353/datatable-in-r-formatting-rows-with-specific-value-category-to-a-percentage

Comment: Thanks - I tried those, but it seems like the both options have issues:  using "tags$head(
      tags$style(
        HTML("tr:first-child, tr:first-child + tr { font-weight: bold }")
      )"

Comment: Sorry, had to continue in next comment as my edit went wrong :)  
...to try and format a table in ui.R works for text formatting, but doesn't work for row background color-I'm guessing the dataTable settings might be overwriting that. The other answer - formatting numbers as percentage by changing them to character and adding % also doesn't work for me, as it means the entire data table is affected by the change and all my numbers are now characters Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

```
library(DT)
dat <- iris[1:4]

rowCallback <- c(
  "function(row, dat, displayNum, index){",
  "  if(index == 3){",
  "    for(var j=1; j<dat.length; j++){",
  "      $('td:eq('+j+')', row)", 
  "        .css('background-color', 'yellow')",
  "        .html(100*dat[j] + '%');",
  "    }",
  "  }",
  "}"
)

datatable(dat, options = list(rowCallback = JS(rowCallback)))
```

Comment: Thanks! Just one note: the third row has `index == 2`, as JavaScript starts counting with 0.

Comment: If I apply this JS code with rowGroup: `rowGroup = list(dataSrc = "lastcolumn)`, it shows last column (grouped column), which is not the case if I don't use JS code. And I didn't loop all thgough last column in, that is for loop starts with: `for(var j=1; j<(dat.length-1); j++){",`

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent - Suppose I just want to format certain cells in that row, not the whole row. I'm not great at JavaScript - I tried for '(const j of [1, 3, 4]){' in your code above, but it failed.